# Using spread to renew a reference to an existing object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object which its keys are defined in an interface. The object contains objects :

```
class S1  { n: number; }
class S2  { n: number; }
class S3  { n: number; }

interface State {
    s1: S1;
    s2: S2;
    s3: S3;
}

var Store: State =
    {
        s1: new S1(),
        s2: new S2(),
        s3: new S3(),
    }
```

I'm modifying an object and keep it in the store again :

```
var s1 = new S1(); //for example
s1.n = 4;
Store.s1 = s1;
```

But now I want to renew the `s1` reference.

I know I can do it via :

```
Store["s1"] = { ...Store["s1"] };
```

But I want to do it via a method which all it accepts is the keys of the Store :

```
function refreshStore<K extends keyof State>(k: K) {
    Store[k] = {
        ...Store[k] //<---error
    };
}
```

But I get an error here ^ :

> Spread types may only be created from object types

**Question:**

How can I make the `refreshStore` method to like the intended `refreshStore('s1')` ?

Basically I want this `refreshStore('s1')` to do

```
  Store["s1"] = { ...Store["s1"] };
```

[**Online Demo**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%0D%0Aclass%20S1%20%20%7B%20n%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20S2%20%20%7B%20n%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20S3%20%20%7B%20n%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%09s1%3A%20S1%3B%0D%0A%09s2%3A%20S2%3B%0D%0A%09s3%3A%20S3%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20Store%3A%20State%20%3D%0D%0A%09%7B%0D%0A%09%09s1%3A%20new%20S1()%2C%0D%0A%09%09s2%3A%20new%20S2()%2C%0D%0A%09%09s3%3A%20new%20S3()%2C%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20refreshStore%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20State%3E(k%3A%20K)%20%7B%0D%0A%09Store%5Bk%5D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09...Store%5Bk%5D%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20s1%20%3D%20new%20S1()%3B%0D%0As1.n%20%3D%204%3B%0D%0AStore.s1%20%3D%20s1%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%0D%0ArefreshStore('s1'))

Comment: It seems a bug/limitation.  You can pass the param `k` as `any` `--->` `k: any`  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14409

Comment: also as ` Store[k] = { ...Store[k.toString()] };`

Comment: @NiritLevi problematic.... see what happens when a new non-object arrives .. https://i.imgur.com/KiMdEYZ.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [current limitations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727), object spread won't work with this generic function. While this will work:

```
function refreshStore(k: keyof State) {
    Store[k] = {...Store[k]};
}
```

Object spread is syntactic sugar for `Object.assign({}, ...)`. It can be used instead:

```
function refreshStore<K extends keyof State>(k: K) {
    Store[k] = Object.assign({}, Store[k]);
}
```

Comment: imho it's strange that it will allow this anyway. I think the generics version error is correct. becuase of this : https://i.imgur.com/KiMdEYZ.jpg -

Comment: Yes, this is the reason why these limitations are still there and debated. I guess this case will be properly handled with `function refreshStore(k: keyof State)`.

Comment: Which case ? The one with number ? You cant do {...4} obviously

Comment: It will cause an error if you have `s4: number` and will work as intended otherwise.